# How would I use jQuery to target the 'a' tag associated with it's html content?

Tags: jquery

In the code below, how would I target the `a` tag associated with the content (e.g. "Blah3") using jQuery? I believe I need to use `find`? I looked through the jQuery doc but couldn't find what I needed.

```
<div id="box">
  <a href="test1.html">Blah1</a>
  <a href="test2.html">Blah2</a>
  <a href="test3.html">Blah3</a>
  <a href="test4.html">Blah4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:contains()`-selector like:

```
$("a:contains('Blah3')").doStuff();
```

See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for further information.